# How can I get the second matcher in regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the second matcher in a regex pattern between `-` and `_` in this string:

```
VA-123456-124_VRG.tif
```

I tried this:

```
Pattern mpattern = Pattern.compile("-.*?_");
```

But I get `123456-124` for the above regex in Java.

I need only `124`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not really a 'duplicate'.  Although the @sAaCh requests the second match, he wants the match before a marker and his approach was not restrictive enough.  Although another solution solves the problem, there is an easier solution to his issue that involves a much simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a formal pattern matcher here, to be a specific as possible.  I would use this pattern:

```
^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^_]+).*
```

and then check the first capture group for the possible match.  Here is a working code snippet:

```
String input = "A-123456-124_VRG.tif";
String pattern = "^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^_]+).*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
}

124
```

### Demo

By the way, there is a one liner which would also work here:

```
System.out.println(input.split("[_-]")[2]);
```

But, the caveat here is that it is not very specific, and might fail for your other data.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that's your format, this will return the requested digits.

*Everything before the underscore that is not a dash*

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\-]+)_");
```

Answer (score 2):

You know you want only digits so be more specific `Pattern.compile("-([0-9]+)_");`

Comment: or simply `-(\d+)_`

Comment: @Reimeus thought about that but \d needs the \ escaped in a string to get it to compile and I come from the Perl world where \d matches all Unicode decimal digits not just [0-9] so I was being explicit in what to match

Answer (score 1):

Try using below regex:

```
.*-(.*?)_
```

What this will do is : **.*** will match all the characters till it finds - . Also, as it is greedy, it will try to find the last possible option, which is just before 24

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NWgZoH/1

JShell Output:

```
jshell> Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*-(.*?)_");
pattern ==> .*-(.*?)_

jshell> Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("VA-123456-124_VRG.tif");
matcher ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*-(.*?)_ region=0,21 lastmatch=]

jshell> if(matcher.find()){
   ...> System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
   ...> }
124
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test case are very low, but if I answer your test case I think below regex can be helpful.

```
-.*-(.*)_
```

then extract first group.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to extract in simple way go ahead with this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s  = "VA-123456-124_VRG.tif";
    System.out.println(s.split("[_-]")[2]);
}
```